# How do these snapshot isolation level configurations interact on a SQL Server 2005 instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, isolation-level

I started troubleshooting a `tempdb` issue we are having on SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition. A developer is getting an error that `tempdb` is out of space. Technically, the error is:

> Transaction aborted when accessing versioned row in table
>   'dbo.inserted' in database 'dbname'. Requested versioned row was not
>   found. Your tempdb is probably out of space. Please refer to BOL on
>   how to configure tempdb for versioning

I looked at the database configuration in `sys.databases` and found the following settings:

```
snapshot_isolation_state: 0

snapshot_isolation_state_desc: OFF

is_read_committed_snapshot_on: 1
```

I looked up what this meant in [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) and the salient information is as follows:

> `snapshot_isolation_state`
>
> State of snapshot-isolation transactions being allowed, as set by the ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION option:
>
> 0 = Snapshot isolation state is OFF (default). Snapshot isolation is disallowed.
>
> 1 = Snapshot isolation state ON. Snapshot isolation is allowed.
>
> 2 = Snapshot isolation state is in transition to OFF state. All transactions have
>   their modifications versioned. Cannot start new transactions using
>   snapshot isolation. The database remains in the transition to OFF
>   state until all transactions that were active when ALTER DATABASE was
>   run can be completed.
>
> 3 = Snapshot isolation state is in transition to
>   ON state. New transactions have their modifications versioned.
>   Transactions cannot use snapshot isolation until the snapshot
>   isolation state becomes 1 (ON). The database remains in the transition
>   to ON state until all update transactions that were active when ALTER
>   DATABASE was run can be completed.
>
> `snapshot_isolation_state_desc`
>
> Description of state of
>   snapshot-isolation transactions being allowed, as set by the
>   ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION option:
>
> - OFF
> - ON
> - IN_TRANSITION_TO_ON
> - IN_TRANSITION_TO_OFF
>
> `is_read_committed_snapshot_on`
>
> 1 = READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option is ON. Read operations under the
>   read-committed isolation level are based on snapshot scans and do not
>   acquire locks.
>
> 0 = READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option is OFF (default). Read operations
>   under the read-committed isolation level use share locks.

If I'm understanding this correctly, `snapshot_isolation_state` is OFF and disallowed. However, the 1 on `is_read_committed_snapshot_on` indicates that the database is using snapshot isolation. How is this possible if it's disallowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @AlexKuznetsov noted, `SNAPSHOT` and `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` are two different isolation levels. As such, `snapshot_isolation_state` indicates the former, while `is_read_committed_snapshot_on` the latter. Here are a few comments that I found that summarize the differences between the two:

> READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT does optimistic reads and pessimistic writes.
> In contrast, SNAPSHOT does optimistic reads and optimistic writes.
>
> ~[Bill Paetzke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192210/bill-paetzke) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779014/251174)

and ...

> [READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT] differs from the SNAPSHOT isolation level in
> that instead of providing a reader with the last committed version of
> the row that was available when the ***transaction*** started
> (SNAPSHOT ISOLATION), a reader gets the last committed version of the
> row that was available when the ***statement*** started
> (READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT).
>
> ~[Uri Dimant](http://dimantdatabasesolutions.blogspot.com/) (*emphasis mine*), [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/e0623b02-7914-414d-a141-9d43f5686924)